# Shows too many arguments for method

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I am trying to insert few data in `apple_reportDB` but I get the error as `Too many arguments for method in the insert query`

```
import scala.slick.driver.MysqlDriver.simple._

case class AppleReport(quantity:String,price:String,sale_amount:String)  

//tables
class Suppliers(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[AppleReport](tag, "apple_report") {

def quantity=column[String]("quantity")
def price=column[String]("price")
def sale_amount=column[String]("sale_amount")

def * =(quantity,price,sale_amount) <> (AffiliateReportFields.tupled,AffiliateReportFields.unapply)
}

   //declaring interface
val suppliers: TableQuery[Suppliers] = TableQuery[Suppliers]

val db=Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apple_reportDB","root","",null, driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  db.withSession { implicit session =>

//create table
suppliers.ddl.create
//Insert data
suppliers += ("apple","cow","cat")

  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Suppliers` table extends `Table[AppleReport]`. Hence your insert statement expects a single object of case class `AppleReport`.

However you are calling the method with 3 Strings `("apple","cow","cat")` and so the error. Change it to `AppleReport("apple","cow","cat")` and your code will work